# MySQL: Selecting people i follow and who follow me back

Tags: mysql

I have a really simple table - `follow` - in which I store followers.

```
user | following
-----------------
1    | 3
```

The above means user 1 is following user 3.

The problem: I want to SELECT everybody who is following user 3 AND i want to see if user 3 is following them back.

The query below does what I want, but it lists ALL users, and I only want the ones who are following user 3. I've tried all sorts of scenarios but the logic is just escaping me today. This is as close as I've been able to get.

```
SELECT 
     u.id,u.username
    ,u.avatar
    ,f.* 
FROM 
    users u 
LEFT JOIN follow f 
    ON f.following=u.id and f.user=3
```

Comment: did you tried RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: @Miki yes, and it returns a wrong result.

Comment: If 1 follows 3 and 3 follows 2, do you want to see all of them ?

Comment: @curiosu, I'm listing all of the people who are following 3. I want to display an icon next to each user that will show if 3 is following them back. So, to answer your question: I only want to see 2 if 2 is following 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with the relation. You want all followers for user 3, so start with the `follow` table and select those records where `following = 3`.

Then you can join the `users` table to get the information for those users. This can be an inner join, since you want those records, and you wouldn't need to return anything if user 3 didn't have any followers.

Then you can join `follow` again, to see if there is a similar relation in the other direction. I made this a left join, so you can check whether that record is found or not.

If you need a list of only those users that follow user 3 and are followed back as well, you can simply change this join into an inner join.

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.username,
    u.avatar,
    case when b.user is null then -- No record in b if 3 didn't follow this user back.
       'User is not following back'
    else
       'User is following back'
    end as back
FROM 
    follow f -- IDs of followers of user 3
    INNER JOIN users u  -- User information of those followers
       ON u.id = f.user
    LEFT JOIN follow b  -- Check if 3 follows them back.
       ON b.user = f.following and
          b.following = u.id
WHERE
    f.following = 3
```

If you need user information for user 3 himself, you can inner join the `users` table against `f` a second time (with a different alias), but I would use a separate query for that.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the query, and for the great explanation too :)